# Printing array elements in reverse order

Tags: java, arrays, stack

```
package SimpleArrayStackofchars;

    public class SimpleArrayStackofchars implements Stack
    {
    protected int capacity;     // The actual capacity of the stack array 
    public static final int CAPACITY = 2;   // default array capacity
    protected Object S[];       // Generic array used to implement the stack 
    protected int top = -1; // index for the top of the stack (-1 = empty stack)
    public SimpleArrayStackofchars() 
    {
        this(CAPACITY); // default capacity
    }
    public SimpleArrayStackofchars(int cap)
    {
        capacity = cap;
        S = new Object[capacity];
    }
    public int size() 
    {
            return (top + 1);
    }
    public boolean isEmpty() 
    {
        return (top == -1);
    }
        public void push(Object element) throws FullStackException 
    {
        if(size() == capacity) 
        {
      //throw new FullStackException
            ("Stack is full. Stack size max is "+ capacity);
     /*can replace previous line with code to double stack size
    */
                doubleArray();
        }
            S[++top] = element;
    }
    public Object top() throws EmptyStackException 
    {
        if (isEmpty())
        throw new EmptyStackException("Stack is empty.");
        return S[top];
    }
    public Object pop() throws EmptyStackException 
    {
        Object element;
        if (isEmpty())
      throw new EmptyStackException("Stack is empty.");
        element = S[top];
        S[top--] = null; // dereference S[top] for garbage collection.
        return element;
    }
    private void doubleArray( )
    {
        Object [ ] newArray;
    System.out.println("Stack is full (max size was "+capacity+"). Increasing to "+(2*capacity));
      //double variable capacity
        capacity = 2*capacity;
        newArray = new Object[ capacity ];
        for( int i = 0; i < S.length; i++ )
        newArray[ i ] = S[ i ];
        S = newArray;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
            Stack S = new SimpleArrayStackofchars();
            S.push("1");
            S.push("2");
            S.push("3");
            S.push("4");
            S.push("5");
            S.push("6");

            while (!S.isEmpty()) 
        {
                System.out.println(S.pop());
            }
        }
    }
```

So  I have this code above, when I run it, it prints the out put. However, I have another question below which I don't understand how to go about it.

This is the Question: Re-write the main method so that there is a call to another method called reverseUsingPop that will take an array of chars and print the array elements in reverse order using the pop method.

Comment: Great, you gave us a lot of mostly irrelevant code and you copy-pasted the question from your assignment. What is it exactly that you are struggling with?

Comment: I don't know how to go about making the reverseUsingPop method. It became a problem for me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you for the tip Sir...

Comment: MY problem is I don't understand the question well. I tried something but I was told is not the way to be done. Any advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have created methods so you know how to do this. You can create another method called reverseUsingPop(char[] characters). and in here execute the loop to print them.

From looking at your code it seems like you should have seen everything to do this. So from your main method you can call that method.

Comment: Don't mistake me. I'm just learning about Stacks. Its a random question I picked. I couldn't understand the notes well. I thought solving a question would help me understand it, as it has done before on other topics. Please Don't mark me to the negative side.

Comment: I wasn't 'marking' you one way or the other, I just gave you an answer without completing the homework for you. I thought it might help you get along ^^

Comment: 'public void reverseUsingPop(char[] x){
      //for ( int j=0; j < x.length; j++ )
            x = new char[6];
            x[0] = '1';
            x[1] = '2';
            x[2] = '3';
            x[3] = '4';
            x[4] = '5';
            x[5] = '6';
             
            for(int j = x.length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        }'

Comment: Is this a good start for the loop? or any other advices

Comment: No that looks quite wrong. I think the idea of the method is that you just print it in reverse. But the way in which you made the array looks odd to me. 
You can use a shorter notation to just instantiate such an array char[] x = {'a','v','z'};

Comment: And then you create a new method (reverseUsingPop) and you pass that array as an argument.  (But I am assuming you meant to say pass an SimpleArrayOfStacks object)

Comment: OK.. I tried something. To be honest I don't understand the question well. So I did this. It printed it out in as I wanted but having not to understand the full requirement of the question. I'm not sure if what I did is correct.

Comment: [code]public char[] reverseUsingPop(){
      //for ( int j=0; j < x.length; j++ )
             char[] x = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'};          
      //      for(int j = x.length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            for ( int j=0; j < x.length; j++ )
            {
                System.out.println(x[j]);
            }
            return x;
        }[code/]